# Eigenvalues of the subtraction of a gram matrix and a psd rank $1$ matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $V$ is $p \times r$ matrix ($r<p$) with rank $r$, then $G=V^TV$ is a $r \times r$ gram matrix with rank $r$. Let $x$ be a $r \times 1$ vector, and $xx^T$ is a psd rank $1$ matrix.

It's already known ([eigenvalues of the subtraction of a PSD matrix and a rank 1 matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138295/eigenvalues-of-the-subtraction-of-a-psd-matrix-and-a-rank-1-matrix)) $G-xx^T$ has at most one negative eigenvalue. My question is what's the condition for $G-xx^T$ to have exactly one negative eigenvalue?

I guess $xx^T$ has to be large in some sense.

Thanks.